# Orthogonal polynomials related to a Jacobi symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-polynomials

I would like to know if the following Hermitian tridiagonal (Jacobi) and symmetric matrix $A(t)$
\begin{equation}
A(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
0&t&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
t&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&t&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&t&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&t&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&t&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&t\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&t&0
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
with $t\geq 1$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$, has a known family of orthogonal polynomials for any odd dimension $(2N+1)\times(2N+1)$. For t=1, they are Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind. If the answer is no, ¿could it be built from Chebyshev polynomials?